# Approximately optimize overlap (masking) of 2d-images on a GPU

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, computer-vision, gpu, torch

Let's say I have two grayscale images. *x* is 100x100 and *y* is 125x125.

*y* is a similar image to *x*. It is also on a different scale.

What I would like is to stretch *y* between 80% to 120% on the height and width dimensions (independently). And then pick a shift for the height and width dimensions, i.e. a start point for cropping to 100x100. Let's call *y' = transform(y, stretch_h, stretch_w, shift_h, shift_w)*. I would like to minimize *|y' - x|*.

i.e. I want to stretch and shift *y* so that it overlaps / masks *x* as well as possible.

I'd like to do this on a GPU, ideally in 100ms or less. I prefer this be *fast* even if it is less exact.

How?

Comment: While a brute-force implementation may work, it will be very expensive even for such small picture because of the quadratic complexity for the shift only, and even bigger for the scale. It should be possible to use an FFT to analyse the phase and deduce the shift far more efficiently. For the scale, this is a bit more complex but I guess the low frequency canbe a good hint to find it efficiently too. Generally FFTs are efficient for correlations like this.

Comment: @JérômeRichard do you mind outlining quickly how this would work? You can do a reduction to 1D if that helps explaining. Or share a link?